# Unable to display username from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I currently am able to view a list of contacts with no issues and would like to be able to view the mentors / tutors for the clients.

The username is stored in another table to the contact information and the mentor ID is stored in the contacts table.

I have followed a tutorial on how to do this but can't get it to work.

I have tried to join the accounts and contacts table together and has stopped the everything from showing. My old code showed everything fine apart from the mentor. (Old code also below)

Error reporting says Warning: Undefined array key "id"

Code;

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT c.id
     , c.name
     , c.last_name
     , c.mobile_number
     , c.status
     , a.username as mentorname
FROM contacts c 
     LEFT JOIN
     accounts a ON c.mentor = a.id
WHERE c.id = ?;');
$stmt->execute([$_GET['c.id']]);
$fullContactInfo = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    
}
```

Display code

```
                <?php if($fullContactInfo == null){
                    echo "<tr><td>No Record Found!</td></tr>";
                }else{ foreach($fullContactInfo as $info){ ?>
                <tr>
                    
                    <td><?php echo $info['name']; ?> <?php echo $info['last_name']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $info['mobile_number']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $info['status']; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $info['mentorname']; ?></td>
```

Table examples

```
Contacts
ID: 1 
Name: Joe Blogs 
Mobile: 1889454 
Status: Current
Mentor: 25

Accounts
ID: 25
Username: jbloggs
```

Old Code

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id,name,last_name,mobile_number,status,dob,mentor,image FROM contacts');
$stmt->execute([$_GET['id']]);
$fullContactInfo = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($fullContactInfo == true){
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT username FROM accounts WHERE id = ?');
    $stmt->execute([ $fullContactInfo['mentor'] ]);
    $fullContactInfo1 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Joe Blogs is his own mentor?

Comment: `$_GET['c.id']` should just be `$_GET['id']`, just like in the old code.

Comment: I've set $stmt->execute([$_GET['id']]); to ID as requested and gives me the same error message. Warning: Undefined array key "id"

Comment: If `$_GET['id']` worked with the old code, I don't see why it wouldn't work with the new code. Did you change the URL used to call the script?

Comment: The old code shouldn't have worked, either. There's no `?` in the first statement to match the argument in `$stmt->execute()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace `$_GET['c.id']` with `$_GET['id']`.

Comment: I've set $stmt->execute([$_GET['id']]); to ID as requested and gives me the same error message. Warning: Undefined array key "id"

Comment: Check whether GET request contains id parameter using ```isset($_GET['id'])```